# (Visual Basic) Sum of integers through 2 numbers

Tags: vb.net, loops

So im pretty close but I continue to get the wrong values. The user is suppose to enter a positive integer and its suppose to add all the integers in between. So if the user enters 5 it should equal 15, 10 would equal 55, etc. But I get 5 = 25, 10, 100.

Changed to decimal to see if that had anything instead of integer and still did nothing. I saw a few things to set decCount to = 1. Did that and the number was closer but still not there.

```
    Dim decSum As Decimal = 0
    Dim decNumber As Decimal = 0
    Dim decCount As Decimal = 0
    Dim strUserInput As String

    strUserInput = InputBox("Enter a positive integer value.", "Input Needed", 0)


    If Decimal.TryParse(strUserInput, decNumber) And (decNumber >= 0) Then
        Do While decCount < decNumber
            decSum = decSum + decNumber
            decCount = decCount + 1
        Loop
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Enter a positive numeric value")
    End If




    MsgBox("The sum of the numbers 1 through " & decNumber & " is " & decSum)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to calculate a factorial of a given input, but in your loop you are adding the same number repeatedly (effectively, you are multiplying the number by itself instead of finding the factorial).

Change this line:

`decSum = decSum + decNumber`

to this:

`decSum = decSum + decCount`

Comment: Wow...that explains so much. Thank you. Also to add I also forgot to add an = to decCount < decNumber. It wasnt adding the last number as well so 1 through 5 was only equaling 10 and not 15 like it should.